# Any multimedia player able to play movies backwards?

Tags: software

Do you know how to play .avi videos backwards with VLC, Potplayer, Kmplayer, BSPlayer or any other common multimedia player in Windows? (without using video editors).

Regards

Comment: I'm sorry, however unless there are more details as to how this related to sound design (and the related disciplines) in an elaborated question, this is not the appropriate place for your question.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the right place for your question. Maybe try asking at http://superuser.com.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with AviSynth I believe, although the most mainstream multimedia players won't make the cut